# How to plot a function line with Markers, such as square, triangle, circle and so on?

Tags: plotting, marker, graphics

How to plot a function line with Markers:

```
f[x_, m_] = m Sin[x]
g[x_, m_] = 2 m Cos[x]
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x,m], g[x,m]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], {m, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

how to add markers like this automatic:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question is vague. There seems to be no need for complicating it further with `Manipulate`. You can photoshop what marker you want and at which points perhaps. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed I agree, when I first read this, I did not understand what the question meant. But I think they meant the Manipulate did not work. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Nasser, the OP has clarified it somewhat in the meantime, but I think that it is still not clear enough for a definitive answer.

Comment: @Syed if you run the code they show as is (from clean kernel) you will notice the Manipulate does not work. So I have no idea how they obtained that screen shot. I am on V 13.2.

Comment: @Nasser I was under the impression that the author of the OP wanted to fix manipulate and change `PlotMarkers` at the same time. Anyway, I like your answer :-)

Comment: If you have a follow up question after the current one was answered please create a separate question. Edits will confuse future readers.

Answer (score 4):

Edit 3: please see below

```
f[x_, m_] := m Sin[x]
g[x_, m_] := 2 m Cos[x]
r0 = Table[{x, f[x, m]}, {x, 0, 10}];
r1 = Table[{x, g[x, m]}, {x, 0, 10}];
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{r0, r1} /. m -> mm, 
  PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", "\[FilledCircle]"}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 10], {mm, 1, 5}]
```

[image: lp]

Edit: thanks to @Syed

If I understand correctly something like the following:

```
f[x_, m_] := m Sin[x]
g[x_, m_] := 2 m Cos[x]

Manipulate[
 DiscretePlot[Evaluate[{f[x, m], g[x, m]}], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, Filling -> None, 
  PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]", 10}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {m, 0, 5}]
```

Edit 2: connecting the points

```
Manipulate[
 DiscretePlot[Evaluate[{f[x, m], g[x, m]}], {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, Filling -> None, 
  PlotMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]", 10}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Joined -> True], {m, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Add: `, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}` for visual benefit.

Comment: @Syed you are absolutely right. Many thanks!

Comment: This plot Discrete Points, but without lines about function, I want keep lines.

Comment: @ChinChingCHAN see the edit please

Comment: @bmf The line seems not smoothly.

Comment: @ChinChingCHAN you wrote on the title that you want different plot markers. This is what I did. I am not sure what you were expecting. Can you perhaps explain what you want?

Comment: @bmf  i add some examples in my question.

Comment: @ChinChingCHAN thanks. I will have a look

Comment: @ChinChingCHAN please have a look at the final edit

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you meant or not. (I assumed you meant your Manipulate was not working). Will delete if not.

[image]

```
f[x_, m_] := m Sin[x]
g[x_, m_] := 2 m Cos[x]
Manipulate[
 Plot[{f[x, m], g[x, m]}, {x, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-5, 5}}],
 {m, 0, 5},
 TrackedSymbols :> {m}]
```

The reason Manipulate did not work, is because `m` did not show in the expression.  The control variable must show in the expression for it to work.